# Stop single line format after [ ] / array?

Tags: prettier

I have a code that looks like this:

```
const fields = [
  { name: 'firstName', label: 'First Name' },
  { name: 'lastName', label: 'Last Name' },
  { name: 'email', label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
  { name: 'password', label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
]
```

But when doing Prettier it make it look like a single line:

```
const fields = [{ name: "firstName", label: "First Name" }, { name: "lastName", label: "Last Name" }, { name: "email", label: "Email", type: "email" }, { name: "password", label: "Password", type: "password" }];
```

Would you say thats is normal / correct way to format this? Any way to disable the single line just for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [`// prettier-ignore`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html).

```
// prettier-ignore
const fields = [
  { name: 'firstName', label: 'First Name' },
  { name: 'lastName', label: 'Last Name' },
  { name: 'email', label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
  { name: 'password', label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
]
```

Then the output should stay same.

But if you are looking for a generic solution, unfortunately it is a bit tricky as you can see [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2716).

Comment: yep one of the solutions i just wish there could be a settings for me to thinker around about these kinds of [ ] code